# Converting some javascript which works on the client side to the server side nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodes

I need to use a client which is available only a a javascript library : https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client

Everytime I try to replace the `<script>` tag with require tag in node js and run it I keep getting this error:

```
sock.js:10
}(function() {
 ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

I have added module.exports. Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score -1):

We would appreciate some of your server-side code ..but maybe run your function inside sock.open

```
 sock.onopen = function() {
    console.log('open');
    (function () {
        var x = "Hello!!";      // I will invoke myself
    })();
 };
```

Comment: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sockjs/1.1.1/sockjs.min.js is the javascript file which I am trying to use in nodejs

Comment: No no ..i mean your script witch you call with node to start your app

Comment: Just a simple require and I am following the documentation here  https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client

Comment: well i dont know i can only guess ...but without your code i cant do anything :P